# How to sum data according to page filter in Dynamics NAV 2009 R2?

Tags: dynamics-nav

I think on every list page has their own default data filter.

Then how would I know what is user currently filter on page if I want to sum data according to  that filter ?

It's not CurrPage.SetSelectionFilter right ? :(

Comment: It is basics. You should read documentation first.

Answer (score 0):

Every page object has an implicit record variable called Rec. The recordset that a user sees on a page comes from that record variable, respecting any filters, sort orders etc. the variable may have. Because it has such an immediate effect on the screen rendering, I think it's a best practice to leave Rec alone as much as possible, letting any added functionality work on another record variable. So how do we transfer filters etc. from Rec to a new record variable (with the same Subtype as Rec)?

Rec.GETFILTERS may seem a good candidate, since it returns the current filters set on Rec. However, please bear in mind that GETFILTERS respects the current filter group: without further actions, it will only return filters set at filter group level 0.

A more efficient approach would be to use COPYFILTERS instead. It allows you to copy all filtering (all filter group levels; including records marks, if I'm mistaken) from one record (i.c. Rec) to another (your custom record variable). After that, you can sum the relevant values in your own record variable.

Comment: May I ask some question ?
I don't know where to place that COPYFILTERS in except OnAfterGetRecord(), but if I use in this trigger, my summation data always change every time when I set focus in others row.